# Convergence of random variables based on shifts of a markov chain

Tags: limits-and-convergence, markov-chains

Suppose we have a discrete time (not necessarily stationary) Markov chain $X=(X_0,X_1,X_2,\dots)$ on $(\Omega, F)$. We assume $X$ is Harris ergodic with an invariant distribution.

Suppose we have a random variable $h_M:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ which depends on the first $M$ random variables, i.e., $h_M(X) = \tilde{h}_M (X_0,\dots,X_{M-1})$, such that $h_M(X_0,\dots,X_{M-1}) \to c$ in probability starting from any $x$ in the state space.

In other words,
$$
P_x(|h_M(X)-c|>\epsilon)\to 0
$$
as $M \to \infty$ for any $\epsilon>0$.

I am wondering about the convergence in probability of $h_M\circ \theta^{M}$, where $\theta^{M}$ denotes the shift by $M$, ie $h_M\circ\theta^{M}(X)=h_M(X_M,X_{M+1},...)$. Does $h_M\circ\theta^{M}(X)\overset{p}{\to}c$ still hold? Also, if instead $h_M(X)\overset{a.s.}{\to}c$ starting from any $x$, do we obtain $h_M\circ\theta^{M}(X)\overset{a.s.}{\to}c$?

When $h_M$ is a sample mean, ie $h_M(X)=M^{-1}\sum_{t=0}^{M-1}f(X_t)$, then the conclusion seems to follow from the convergence of $h_M(X)$ and $h_{2M}(X)$.